ELK Stack with Docker and multiple server for UDP logging
I'm trying to setup an ELK stack (kibana, logstash and elastic search) in portainer which should receive loggings from pc's around the world.
The thing I'm not sure is how the proper setup should look like, so the performance for the clients is good.
Lets say portainer is running in Europe in a docker container and there are users in America, Europe, Australia and Asia.
What would be a proper setup? I guess I need a server on each continent in my stack but how do I redirect the loggings to the "fastest" endpoint?
Would be great if anyone could refer me to some keywords and articles where I can find a solution how this setup could look like
Right now I have the ELK stack on my local computer with docker and send UDP messages (json content) to my stack.
The frequency of these messages can be several per second per client. There are like 600-700 (maybe more in the future) online at the same time around the world.
My elasticsearch.yml
cluster.name: docker-cluster
network.host: 0.0.0.0

xpack.license.self_generated.type: trial
xpack.security.enabled: true

Here is my docker-compose.yml
setup:
profiles:
  - setup
build:
  context: setup/
  args:
    ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
init: true
volumes:
  - ./setup/entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh:ro,Z
  - ./setup/lib.sh:/lib.sh:ro,Z
  - ./setup/roles:/roles:ro,Z
environment:
  ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD:-}
  LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
  KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD: ${KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD:-}
  METRICBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${METRICBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
  FILEBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${FILEBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
  HEARTBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${HEARTBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
  MONITORING_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${MONITORING_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
  BEATS_SYSTEM_PASSWORD: ${BEATS_SYSTEM_PASSWORD:-}
networks:
  - elk
depends_on:
  - elasticsearch

elasticsearch:
build:
  context: elasticsearch/
  args:
    ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
volumes:
  - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro,Z
  - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:Z
ports:
  - 9200:9200
  - 9300:9300
environment:
  node.name: elasticsearch
  ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
  ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD:-}
  discovery.type: single-node
networks:
  - elk
restart: unless-stopped

logstash:
build:
  context: logstash/
  args:
    ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
volumes:
  - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro,Z
  - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro,Z
ports:
  - 5044:5044/udp
  - 50000:50000/tcp
  - 9600:9600
environment:
  LS_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx256m
  LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
networks:
  - elk
depends_on:
  - elasticsearch
restart: unless-stopped

kibana:
build:
  context: kibana/
  args:
    ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
volumes:
  - ./kibana/config/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro,Z
ports:
  - 5601:5601
environment:
  KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD: ${KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD:-}
networks:
  - elk
depends_on:
  - elasticsearch
restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:

my logstash.conf
    input {
    tcp {
        port => 50000
    }
    udp {
        port => 5044
        codec => json
  }
}

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
        target => "parsed_message" 
        skip_on_invalid_json => true
    }

    mutate {
        rename => {
        "[parsed_message][message]" => "message"
        "[parsed_message][logLevel]" => "logLevel"
        "[parsed_message][application]" => "application"
        "[parsed_message][username]" => "username"
        "[parsed_message][computer]" => "computer"
        "[parsed_message][timestamp]" => "timestamp"
        }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        #index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        #hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
        data_stream => "true"          
        data_stream_type => "logs"       
        data_stream_dataset => "logstash" 
        data_stream_namespace => "default" 
        user => "logstash_internal"
        password => "${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD}"
    }
}

my kibana.yml
    xpack.fleet.agents.fleet_server.hosts: [ http://fleet-server:8220 ]

xpack.fleet.outputs:
  - id: fleet-default-output
    name: default
    type: elasticsearch
    hosts: [ http://elasticsearch:9200 ]
    is_default: true
    is_default_monitoring: true

xpack.fleet.packages:
  - name: fleet_server
    version: latest
  - name: system
    version: latest
  - name: elastic_agent
    version: latest
  - name: docker
    version: latest
  - name: apm
    version: latest

xpack.fleet.agentPolicies:
  - name: Fleet Server Policy
    id: fleet-server-policy
    description: Static agent policy for Fleet Server
    monitoring_enabled:
      - logs
      - metrics
    package_policies:
      - name: fleet_server-1
        package:
          name: fleet_server
      - name: system-1
        package:
          name: system
      - name: elastic_agent-1
        package:
          name: elastic_agent
      - name: docker-1
        package:
          name: docker
  - name: Agent Policy APM Server
    id: agent-policy-apm-server
    description: Static agent policy for the APM Server integration
    monitoring_enabled:
      - logs
      - metrics
    package_policies:
      - name: system-1
        package:
          name: system
      - name: elastic_agent-1
        package:
          name: elastic_agent
      - name: apm-1
        package:
          name: apm
        # See the APM package manifest for a list of possible inputs.
        # https://github.com/elastic/apm-server/blob/v8.5.0/apmpackage/apm/manifest.yml#L41-L168
        inputs:
          - type: apm
            vars:
              - name: host
                value: 0.0.0.0:8200
              - name: url
                value: http://apm-server:8200


For a self-hosted/cloud-hosted clustered setup, you would want to have geo-region DNS deployment for your main front-end. Most higher level DNS providers can do this - https://www.cloudns.net/geodns/ for example.
Caution!
It is not advised to 'host' your ELK much less your Kibana on public IP space.
It is very wise to have that behind a VPN and if you didn't use a VPN and choose to do a Zerotrust style delivery instead, then ZT providers like Cloudflare have the ability to network and allow users from other geo regions to get to the one closest to them, such as - https://developers.cloudflare.com/data-localization/how-to/zero-trust/.
In each case, clustered setup is a very unique detail, quite unique to not only the feature being clustered but even more so how you balance the agencies of load on it (what each part is doing when, how users/jobs get shared, how recovery/upgrades/backup happens).
Could you expand your vision?
Of interest are how/where are you going to host it, how do you expect your user to get to it, what kind of perimeter/login surface were you going to have around your environment(s)?
There are ways to add a container with config that could start getting you close to your vision but more information about the packaging/expectations will help.
